# matplotlib boxplot positions sets unexpected xlim

Tags: python, matplotlib, boxplot

Why x ticks are located differently for the boxplot if the values are scaled?

```
f, (top, bottom) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

data = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]

x = np.asanyarray([2,4,5.5])

top.boxplot(data, positions=x * 1e-1, widths=1e-1 );
bottom.boxplot(data, positions=x);
```

[image]

I would expect top and bottom plots almost match and differ only in the labels in x. That is the same behavior as for the plot function:

```
f, (top, bottom) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

data = [1, 2, 3]

x = np.asanyarray([2,4,5.5])

top.plot(x, data);
bottom.plot(x * 1e-1, data);
```

[image]

How can I make a boxplot with custom positions and make these position automatically occupy free space as if were a regular plot?

Answer (score 0):

The solution I just found is in calling `relim` function manually once the plot is made:

```
f, (top, bottom) = plt.subplots(nrows=2)

data = [[1,4],[2,5],[3,6]]

x = np.asanyarray([2,4,5.5])

top.boxplot(data, positions=x * 1e-1, widths=1e-1 );
top.relim()
bottom.boxplot(data, positions=x);
```

What I am still curious to learn is that why x lim is set automatically for plot and not for boxplot?

[image]